# BigQuery regex to find string that contains chinese characters

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to find string that contains any chinese characters.

I have the following query in PostgreSQL which works as expected.

```
with tmp as (
    select '中文zz' as word
    union all
    select '中文' as word
    union all
    select 'english' as word
    union all
    select 'にほんご' as word
    union all
    select 'eng–lish' as word
)
select word,
word ~* '[\x4e00-\x9fff\x3400-\x4dbf]'
from tmp
```

Results:

```
中文zz       true
中文         true
english     false
にほんご     false
eng–lish    false
```

However, if I convert this SQL in BigQuery, it does not produce the same result.

```
with tmp as (
    select '中文zz' as word
    union all
    select '中文' as word
    union all
    select 'english' as word
    union all
    select 'にほんご' as word
    union all
    select 'eng–lish' as word
)
select word,
regexp_contains(word, r'[\x4e00-\x9fff\x3400-\x4dbf]')
from tmp
```

Results:

```
中文zz      true
中文        false
english     true
にほんご     false
eng–lish    true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex with `BigQuery` :

```sql
with tmp as (
    select '中文zz' as word
    union all
    select '中文' as word
    union all
    select 'english' as word
    union all
    select 'にほんご' as word
    union all
    select 'eng–lish' as word
)
select word,
regexp_contains(word, '''[\u4E00-\u9FA5]''')
from tmp
```

The result is :

[image]